# keras installed but doesn't have subsequent functions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I installed keras 2.2.4 and tensorflow 1.12.0 in my Win10 computer. From Anaconda navigator screen, it seems all needed ones were installed.
[image]

[image]
However, my keras doesn't have any subsequent functions (e.g. keras.model or keras.layers). When I `import keras`, it can work, but if I changed to `import keras.models` or `from keras.models import Sequential`, it said **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.models'**. All other subsequent ones like keras.layers or keras.datasets didn't work either.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have any file keras.py? If yes, it's trying to import that Keras.

Comment: in which folder I can check whether I have this? or use which command? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the versions mentioned by you,

'import keras.models' or 'from keras.models import Sequential' works fine.

Just to confirm I installed keras and tensorflow in the new environment and it was working fine.

Try reinstalling the packages using pip and check once. It should work.